# After the BIOS boots, how can I dump memory?

Tags: memory, dump, firewire

After the BIOS boots, I'd like to dump the memory of the system. I have read about how it is possible using FireWire to do this, but have found no hard instructions or tutorials about it.

Comment: Could you do it in a virtual machine, or do you need to see the memory of a specific bare-metal machine?

Answer (score 0):

There wont be anything in memory except the BIOS, the constructs it has created, and any option rom data.

It would be possible to write a custom boot sector, that copies everything in RAM to a disk, but I'm struggling to see the usefulness.

Comment: Wouldn't writing a custom boot sector change what is in memory?

Comment: Something has to get loaded into memory in order to run on the computer... Most normal computers don't have a JTAG port to read memory contents externally. (Most JTAG ports are also somewhat slow)

Comment: Firewire method works with the Windows Firewire drive being loaded (The driver improperly grants unfiltered DMA access to the firewire HBA). I wouldn't be surprised if it has been fixed in more recent versions of Windows. Here's a bit of how to get it working: http://www.storm.net.nz/projects/16

Comment: So the firewire trick only works post-Windows load? I'm trying to see what's in memory right after boot up from the BIOS, before a bootloader or OS.

Comment: Correct, the Firewire exploits a security vulnerability in the Windows Firewire driver (at the same time technically altering the RAM/configuration of the machine). The only way to get an absolutely clean copy of the memory would be through a JTAG port; and those are very rare. A boot sector program that dumps memory would only "comprimise" 512 bytes of RAM and at a known location (segment 7C0). What specifically are you after?

Answer (score 0):

write a small custom mbr which uses int 0x13 AH=43h: Extended Write Sectors to Drive in order to write memory to disk.  Just remember the 512 bytes starting at 0x7c00 is you. That memory will not be filled with anything before bios loads mbr there.  If you use that method, it does not depend on FireWire which is an uncommon interface.

Here you can find a general overview of low level system memory: https://wiki.osdev.org/Memory_Map_(x86)

The location 0x7c00 is considered free memory. so its not used by bios or other system things, just the bootloader is put there but that's not important. you can replace it with 0 if you want a pristine copy of memory.....

The memory map can help you write out certain parts of memory which have contents so you don't need to dump bunches of 0s.

Alternatively to writing to disk you could dump over serial if you have a serial port to connect to with BIOS int 0x14 which could be more convenient depending on your setup.